# Difficulty with DisqusSharp

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, disqus

I am playing around with DisqusSharp:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using WWB.DisqusSharp.Model.DisqusService;
using WWB.DisqusSharp.Infrastructure.Hammock;

namespace DisqusSharpTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("foo");
            Console.In.ReadLine();

            IDisqusService disqus = new HammockDisqusService("myKey");
            IEnumerable<string> names = disqus.GetThreadList("myForumId", new StartLimitArgs { Start = 0, Limit = 5 })
                                      .Payload.Select(disqusThread => disqusThread.Title);

            foreach (string name in names) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After I add references to `WWB.DisqusSharp.dll`, as well as `Hammock.dll` and `Newtonsoft.Json.dll`, this appears to work fine. I use Visual Studio's autocorrect feature and it adds `using` statements for the `WWB` classes.

However, when I click "start debugging" or "start without debugging", it complains of a build error, saying that the namespace `WWB` cannot be found. I then re-add the reference, and it works again, until I hit "start debugging" again.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be WWB, guess I should add disqussharp to the watch list. Anyhow, I'm not sure the problem you are having, but I'd suggest using the [nuget package](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/disqussharp) as a test to make sure things get wired up correctly.