# X-P2P-PeerDist header: where does it come from?

Tags: http-headers

I'm seeing this HTTP header on some requests made to my server:

```
X-P2P-PeerDist: Version=1.0
```

I'm aware of this: http://www.faqs.org/patents/app/20110016220#ixzz3g3X8lSYF, but I would like to know what are the known clients sending that header.

Any idea?

UPDATE: as requested, i'm including the other headers sent with the request (I've obfuscated some private stuff that are related to our customer with ***):

```
GET http://***.com/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, */*
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; SLCC2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
X-P2P-PeerDist: Version=1.0
UA-CPU: AMD64
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, peerdist
Host: ***.com
Cookie: SMSESSION=***; OrgName=***; authCookie=***; ASP.NET_SessionId=***
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

The user agent seems to indicate IE11 (`Trident/`) in IE7 mode (`compatible; MSIE 7.0`), but I'm not getting the X-P2P-PeerDist header when I'm using this config, so I don't think it's directly related.

Comment: What is the User-Agent header value?

Comment: @mark I've updated my post, please see the update

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/74/Timeline_of_web_browsers.svg says that Trident exists from IE 4.

https://www.whatismybrowser.com/developers/custom-parse?useragent=Mozilla%252F4.0+%2528compatible%253B+MSIE+7.0%253B+Windows+NT+6.1%253B+Win64%253B+x64%253B+Trident%252F7.0%253B+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727%253B+SLCC2%253B+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729%253B+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729%253B+InfoPath.3%253B+.NET4.0C%253B+.NET4.0E%2529&SecurityID=d003b9f6227906e7a9f5d9f306855bdd31f60c82&action_submit=Analyse+this+user+agent  suggests that it is IE 7

Comment: application/x-ms-xbap indicates that it is a browser with XML Browser Applications (Silverlight etc.) present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is one of the headers used in the [`PeerDist`](http://www.iana.org/assignments/message-headers/message-headers.xhtml) peer content caching protocol. It has never been standardized and are not even registered with the [IANA registry for HTTP headers](http://www.iana.org/assignments/message-headers/message-headers.xhtml).

It is known to be sent from some recent versions of [Internet Explorer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2013/07/02/troubleshooting-and-fixing-session-cookie-problems-in-ie11.aspx), [.NET HTTP clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216738/your-api-key-is-not-valid-on-this-domain-when-calling-disqus-from-wp7) and [SilverLight HTTP clients](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/03/18/silverlight-3-offline-update-framework.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the effort. However I'm looking for a more precise answer in order to replicate the environment. For instance, my version of IE(11) on Windows and Windows Phone does not send the header. From your links, I'm thinking it might be sent by IE when embedded in another application. Could it also be added by a third-party on the network? (proxy? router? if so, which ones?)

Comment: I think not many people can tell you exactly under what condition will the header be sent, unless they have the experience first-hand. Frankly I am not one of them, sorry. I think you can definitely try making some HTTP connections from .NET and SilverLight.

Comment: BTW, http://git.kaarsemaker.net/libgit2/blob/dd5e74e59af7597938bdcedd3cb240d3c693ea1f/src/transports/winhttp.c  seems to suggest that WinHTTP adds the header. `Strip unwanted headers (X-P2P-PeerDist, X-P2P-PeerDistEx) that WinHTTP adds itself.`

Answer (score 2):

I’m relatively certain that this header is send when if the client is configured to use [BranchCache](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425028.aspx) and a request is made using WinHTTP. About BranchCache:

> To optimize WAN bandwidth, BranchCache copies content from your main office content servers and caches the content at branch office locations, allowing client computers at branch offices to access the content locally rather than over the WAN. ([Source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd996641%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)).

When testing here locally, a client that has BranchCache enabled sends the **X-P2P-PeerDist** header, while a brand new client (no BranchCache configured) does not sent it.

The underlying protocol seems for is *Peer Content Caching and Retrieval* ([MS-PCCRTP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd341501.aspx)), as the section [Message Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd359014.aspx) from the protocol description defines **X-P2P-PeerDist** as one of the HTTP header extension it uses.

However, the document *[BranchCache Deployment Guide for Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19558)* lists other MS-PCCx protocols but not MS-PCCRTP. So I don't have an external evidence that this header is caused by a BranchCache enabled client.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this in IE11 + compatibility mode on Windows 7, connected to an intranet application and downloading a docx file. The request only appears when downloading a document. All requests are going through an F5 load balancer. In other non-download requests on the same browser and same application, the X-p2p-peerdist header is missing.